# TinyMCE issue where all text is getting centered if user centers top line

Tags: asp.net, html, tinymce

I have a website where i embed tiny mce to allow the users to edit the main content on the site.

The issue is that if a users highlights the top row and clicks center button, the text alignment for the entire document (multiple paragraphs) all get centered.

has anyone seen this or have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the paragraphs are truly multiple paragraphs (i.e. `<P>` tags in the source and not simply two line-breaks (i.e. `<br />`) tags?

If that is the case then it is simply a matter of training your users to push <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: there are line breaks in the view in tinymce

Comment: what is wrong with having 2 line breaks versus paragraphs.  if you have line breaks, does that cause tinymce to not work ?

Comment: A p tag is the semantically correct way of forming a paragraph, a linebreak (br tag) is for breaking into a new line within a paragraph. So the tinyMCE editor is applying the centre command to the block you are in, i.e. the paragraph, heading etc...